# Can't create azure bot service - "This MSA App ID is already in use"

Tags: azure, azure-bot-service

Trying to play with the newly announced service, but am having problems getting started.

1. Entered name, subscription, etc.
2. Got my Microsoft App ID, entered it into the form
3. Selected C#
4. Selected any one of the templates
5. When I click Create Bot I get "This MSA App ID is already in use"

What do I need to do?

Comment: I also got similar error. I tried thrice..created three different APPS and was successful for the third time :-) Here is my article on Azure Bot Service https://praveenkumarsreeram.com/2016/11/17/build-your-bot-quickly-using-azure-bot-service/ Looks like some error :-)

Comment: @Prawin Thanks -- I clicked the Manage and created a set (app id / password) and used that instead of the previous values and it worked ok.

Comment: Cool.. Good to her that :-)

Comment: This seems silly. Basically the error message is saying that for you to deploy to Azure you need to do it from scratch and can't use an existing MS chatbot..? Really don't want to have to go through all of that - has anybody found a way round this? Or are we missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I clicked the Manage and created a set (app id / password) and used that instead of the previous values and it worked ok thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

**Background to my answer:** For some reason, my current Bot Service stopped working and I had to create a new Bot Service to provide the back-end for my already published bot. However, when you try to create a new Bot Service using your already published bot App ID and App secret, you will get the same message ("This MSA App ID is already in use").

Solution: Delete the old Bot service that does not work anymore. Then create a new Bot Service (with new App ID and App secret) with the same name as your old Bot Service name (**so the messaging endpoint URL will look similar**). This process will create a new bot in your bot framework portal (under My bots). Now you need to do two things:

1. Go to your newly created Bot Service (In Azure portal), find the application settings under "settings" tab. In application settings, replace the MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword with the AppId and App secret (= app password) from your published bot. You can find the App ID and password of your published bot from the [Bot Framework portal](https://dev.botframework.com).
2. In the Bot Framework portal, find your newly created bot under "My bots". You need to copy the messaging endpoint of this bot, into your messaging endpoint of your old (published) bot. In the portal, click on "Edit" besides the "Details" section. Scroll down and copy the messaging endpoint. Go to "My bots" again and click on your old bot. Click the "Edit" besides the "Details" section and paste the endpoint URL there.

Now your newly created bot service (Azure portal) is connected to your old published bot (in Bot Framework Portal). You can go ahead and delete the newly created bot in your Bot Framework portal, as you do not need it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you already registered a Microsoft Application with that ID. You need to create a new App Registration and use that one: https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList