# Unable to register new bot service: getting "MsaAppId: MsaAppId is already in use.."

Tags: azure-bot-service

I'm facing issues with new bot channel registration. Everytime when I try creating a new bot registration, I'm getting deployment error, and I'm getting the same error "MsaAppId: MsaAppId is already in use..". But each time I'm providing different AppId, in fact I tried generating new microsoft app ids using different user accounts from "https://apps.dev.microsoft.com". But no use getting the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't create azure bot service - "This MSA App ID is already in use"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40666062/cant-create-azure-bot-service-this-msa-app-id-is-already-in-use)

Comment: Although the error message is the same, this is in fact not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/40666062/2646573. It seems something's broken at Microsoft's end during the past few days, because following the documented steps for creating a Bot Channels Registration in Azure (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#create-a-bot-channels-registration) now fails every time, even when selecting the option for auto-generating the MSA App.

Comment: The team is aware of this issue and is releasing a fix asap.  Please follow along here for updates: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4863