# How can I programmatically create an Microsoft MsaAppId and MsaAppPassword via the Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

In order to make the automated deploy of chatbot applications I need to create the MsaAppId and MsaAppPassword and pass them to the Azure SDK or the ARM Template.

If I go to https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList and create the App there I can get the MsaAppId and MsaAppPassword and use that. But of course that is of no use when I'm trying to automate the deploy process.

I was able to found two year old [question here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40666062/cant-create-azure-bot-service-this-msa-app-id-is-already-in-use) that's about the same thing. What I was able to take from that is that I'm supposed to do this through the Microsoft Graph API. However I don't know if the API has changed, but I wasn't able to reproduce the same results reported in the answer that was chosen as correct.

When I make a request to the same endpoint with a similar payload this is what I get back from the API:

[image]

It's worth mentioning that I'm using an personal @outlook.com account to log into Azure.

I'm still not sure about the correlation between MSA Apps and my Azure account apps. If log into my azure account and go to my apps I don't see the apps that were created through https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList (and I'm using the same account, of course).

Comment: Could you elaborate on "f course that is of no use when I'm trying to automate the deploy process"? You generally don't need a new App ID for each deployment.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur You need when each deployment is for a different application. I'm trying to create a web API that it's able to create and deploy a new chatbot application and return the DirectLine secret to the caller. So if I call the API 10 times I'll deploy 10 different bot applications.

Comment: I'm still not sure I follow why you need distinct App IDs. Generating multiple App IDs would also mean you require multiple User Consent flows (and potentially Admin Consent flows, depending on the scopes you require).

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I'm not sure if you are familiar with the Azure Bot Service. But every new chatbot application requires unique MsaAppId and a MsaAppPassword associated with it. So, for every new chatbot that my application is to deploy I need to provide a different MsaAppId and different MsaAppPassword. I need to put this information the the Web.config of my application code.

Comment: Bot registration includes some additional bits beyond atraditional App registration. I suspect what you're looking for here is [`Microsoft.Azure.Management.BotService`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.BotService/0.9.1-preview). This SDK handles the management side of the bot service (as opposed to the client side in the Graph or Bot SDKs).

Answer (score 2):

You still cant automate the creation of converged AD application principals. This is a limitation of the current Graph v2 API, read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-register-an-app)  and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-limitations).
You have to register them in the [Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com)

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to create an app registration and it works with creating a bot. It creates it in azure AD though and requires an app registration with the permission to read and write to all applications.

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient;
    using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
    
    namespace AzureRegistration
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Manages app registrations in azure AD
        /// </summary>
        public class AzureAppRegistrationManager
        {
            private const string resource = "https://graph.windows.net/";
    
    
            private readonly string tenant;
    
            private readonly string appId;
    
            private readonly string appPassword;
            
            private string AuthString => $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}";
    
            private string appToken = null;
    
            /// <summary>
            /// Connects to the tenant using the client credentials passed in.
            /// Requires users to have permissions to create app registrations.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="tenant">Tenant name</param>
            /// <param name="appId">App ID</param>
            /// <param name="appPassword">App Password</param>
            public AzureAppRegistrationManager(string tenant, string appId, string appPassword)
            {
                this.tenant = tenant;
                this.appId = appId;
                this.appPassword = appPassword;
            }
    
            /// <summary>
            /// Creates an app registration with a password that expires in 2 years. Returns the app ID of the application
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="appPassword">Value of the password</param>
            /// <param name="appTitle">App display name</param>
            /// <param name="identifierUrl">The identifier URL. This must be unique across the azure AD</param>
            /// <param name="availableToOtherTenants">True to be available to other tenants</param>
            /// <returns>Returns the app ID</returns>
            public async Task<string> CreateAppRegistrationAsync(string appPassword, string appTitle, string identifierUrl, bool availableToOtherTenants = false)
            {
                IApplication app = new Application()
                {
                    DisplayName = appTitle,
                    AvailableToOtherTenants = availableToOtherTenants,
                    IdentifierUris = new string[] { identifierUrl }
                };
    
                PasswordCredential password = new PasswordCredential()
                {
                    StartDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    EndDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(2).DateTime,
                    Value = appPassword
                };
    
                app.PasswordCredentials.Add(password);
    
                ActiveDirectoryClient client = GetActiveDirectoryClientAsApplication();
    
                await client.Applications.AddApplicationAsync(app);
    
                return app.AppId;
            }
    
            /// <summary>
            /// Deletes the app with the app ID
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="appId">Application ID to be deleted</param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public async Task DeleteAppRegistrationAsync(string appId)
            {
                ActiveDirectoryClient client = GetActiveDirectoryClientAsApplication();
    
                try
                {
                    IApplication app = await client.Applications.Where(a => a.AppId == appId).ExecuteSingleAsync();
                    await app.DeleteAsync();
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException) { }
            }
            
            private ActiveDirectoryClient GetActiveDirectoryClientAsApplication()
            {
                Uri servicePointUri = new Uri(resource);
                Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri, tenant);
                ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, GetTokenForApplicationAsync);
                    //async () => await GetTokenForApplication());
                return activeDirectoryClient;
            }
    
            /// <summary>
            /// Get Token for Application.
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns>Token for application.</returns>
            private async Task<string> GetTokenForApplicationAsync()
            {
                if (appToken == null)
                {
                    AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(
                        AuthString,
                        false);
    
                    // Configuration for OAuth client credentials 
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(appPassword))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(
                            "Client secret not set. Please follow the steps in the README to generate a client secret.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(
                            appId,
                            appPassword);
                        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult =
                            await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred);
                        appToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
                    }
                }
                return appToken;
            }
        }
    }
```